# Creating a color image in j2me

Tags: java, image, java-me, midp, cldc

I need to create different image size with green color in microedition, is it possible?

I need to create the image on the fly without loading an image.

Comment: I need to create the image on the fly without loading an image

Comment: I'm tried to create images on the fly for testing a servlet

Comment: I need to create arround 1000,000 on the fly images and send it to the servlet

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/DrawanImageandsavetopng.htm

change the color from black to green in example. 
If you want images to be unique draw unique numbers instead of text. 
if you don't want to use text in the image then simply draw something but start the drawing at a random location in the image.

Out of curiosity are you trying to test the servlet or the phone app?

Sorry earlier I missed that you wanted to achieve this in J2ME
See the link below
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/MutableImageExample.htm

Comment: sorry missed the part in your question that you wanted to do this in j2me

Comment: I'm Testing the servlet. Thank you for your response !
Now I'm trying to convert that image to byte[] array.